# For $B$ a finitely presented $A$-algebra, $H_{B/A}$ is non zero $H$ referring to the smooth locus/radical of Jacobian ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading a paper on Neron-desingularization found here http://hlombardi.free.fr/Popescu-Luminy2015.pdf. Specifically I am reading Lemma 9 on page 10. In the setup of this lemma $A$ is a Noetherian, local, dimension 1 domain that contains the rational numbers and $B$ is a finite type $A$-algebra. Say we have that $B=A[X]/I$ where $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$.

Defined earlier is the smooth locus: $H_{B/A}$ is the radical in $B$ of $\sum \Delta (f_1,...,f_r)[(f_1,...,f_r):I)]$ the sum being taken over all finite sets of elements $f_1,...,f_r$ of $I$ and where $\Delta (f_1,...,f_r)$ is the ideal of B generated by all $r\times r$-minors of the Jacobian matrix $(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)$.

In lemma 9 it is stated that $H_{B/A}\neq 0$. What about the example where $I=(a)$ for some element $a\in A$. Don't we then have that any partial derivative of a polynomial in $(a)$ is $0$ and any quotient ideal is also $0$ since $A$ is a domain? In this case isn't $H_{B/A}=0$?

I'd very much appreciate it if someone could help me through my misunderstanding.

Thanks